# PowerShell - type no inside every directory and open up notepad2

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, powershell

Do you know the `notepad` command in PowerShell or cmd.exe? I would like to do the same for [NotePad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.HTML) I would like to type the following command inside PowerShell and open up the me.txt file;

```
PS C:\Apps> no -me
```

how can I configure that?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to create an alias?

Comment: @jscott I would like to type this `no -me` inside PowerShell and open up the me.txt file with Notepad2. I saw some guy doing that and wonder how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an alias, except the -me would only be me.

```
PS > set-alias no notepad
PS > no me
```

You would have to set one to the full path of notepad2.exe so it would be something like

```
PS > set-alias no c:\my\customdirectory\notepad2.exe
```

Comment: useful but it gets me notepad not notepad2 :s